# When I am running XCUItest on AWS device farm I am getting Setup Test skipped: Not enough suites found to execute

Tags: amazon-web-services, xcuitest

I have followed all the steps mentioned on below link.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-ios-xctest-ui.html and

https://www.mobdesignapps.fr/blog/2016/9/17/running-your-test-on-aws-device-farm?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=answer&utm_term=37184633

but still no luck.

Comment: Please add your code here so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I found the solution Thanks. The thing is I was not using test word before function so test build was not recognizing my tests.

Comment: you should not be even possible to run the tests in Xcode without "test" at the beginning of function name, because the "diamond" for test run will not appear without it.